# How to wait result from OKHTTP response without freezing app

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

When I use CountDownLatch, the application freezes until the result is received, it is fashionable to avoid this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Offload network & i/o tasks to a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in another thread. Also you can do it in [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html)

I recommend get data with

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { 
   val dat = getdata()
   launch(Dispatchers.Main){ setInMyView(dat) }
}
```